# Jackson: Registering a custom XML serializer for Map data structure

Tags: java, xml, json, jackson, jax-rs

Jackson jax-rs content providers are used in our jax-rs based REST API project, to handle json and xml content type. In response POJO, we have map structure and our requirement is to serialize this map structure as a List in XML and as a Map in JSON format. (The map keys contain whitespaces and hence its not possible to convert these keys as XML element names). In order to achieve this we have implemented a custom serializer for XML...

JSON:

```
"properties":{
    "a b c":{
            "name": "a b c",   
            "value": "xyz"
            }
}
```

XML:

```
<property name="a b c" value="xyz"/>
```

PropertyMapSerializer:

```
public class PropertyMapSerializer extends
        JsonSerializer<Map<String, Property>> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Map<String, Property> value, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {

        provider.defaultSerializeValue(value.values(), jgen);
    }
}
```

JAX-RS context resolver is configured to resolve the XMLMapper instance configured to use this serializer.

```
@Provider
@Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public class XmlMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<XmlMapper> {
    private final XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();

    @Override
    public XmlMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return xmlMapper;
    }

    public XmlMapperContextResolver() {
        JacksonXmlModule module = new JacksonXmlModule();
        module.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);

        //Compilation error while adding Serializer for Map and HashMap class. 
        //Error: The method addSerializer(Class<? extends T>, JsonSerializer<T>) in the type SimpleModule is not applicable for the arguments (Class<Map>, PropertyMapSerializer)
        //module.addSerializer(HashMap.class, new PropertyMapSerializer());
        //module.addSerializer(Map.class, new PropertyMapSerializer());

        //This works
        module.addSerializer(PropertyMap.class, new PropertyMapSerializer());

        xmlMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
        xmlMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
        xmlMapper.registerModule(module);
    }
}
```

Where PropertyMap is a subclass of HashMap:

```
public class PropertyMap extends HashMap<String, Property> {
}
```

Response POJO:

```
public class ResponsePOJO {
    //Commenting out as serializer couldn't be added for HashMap
    //private Map<String, Property> properties = new HashMap<String, Property>();
    private Map<String, Property> properties = new PropertyMap();
}
```

Could you please let me know, why I am not able add serializer for HashMap while adding serializer for its subclass us supported? Because of this I am forced to create subclasses of standard data structures to add custom serializers.

But at the same time adding custom serializer using annotations for Map is supported and it works:

```
@JsonSerialize(using=PropertyMapSerializer.class)
private Map<String, Property> properties = new HashMap<String, Property>();
```

Adding serializer in this manner would make the serializer applicable for both json and xml format. Unfortunately, I can't do this as this serializer is only applicable for XML format. Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
@JsonProperty("rowdata")
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "ROWDATA")
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ROW")
private List<Row> rows;
```

and Row class is

```
@JsonSerialize(using = Row.Serializer.class)
public class Row {

    private HashMap<String, String> data;

    public HashMap<String, String> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(HashMap<String, String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public static class Serializer extends StdSerializer<Row> {

        public Serializer() {
            this(null);
        }

        public Serializer(Class<Row> t) {
            super(t);
        }

        @Override
        public void serialize(Row row, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
            if (jsonGenerator instanceof ToXmlGenerator) {
                final ToXmlGenerator xmlGenerator = (ToXmlGenerator) jsonGenerator;
                jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : row.getData().entrySet()) {
                    if (item.getValue() == null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    xmlGenerator.setNextIsAttribute(true);

                    jsonGenerator.writeFieldName(item.getKey());
                    jsonGenerator.writeString(item.getValue());
                }
                jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
            } else {
                jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : row.getData().entrySet()) {
                    if (item.getValue() == null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    jsonGenerator.writeFieldName(item.getKey());
                    jsonGenerator.writeString(item.getValue());
                }
                jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's work for both JSON and XML.
My main goal was to represent row data as XML attributes of ROW element. Also I want same data structure for JSON.
Here how does it look in response:
XML

```
<ROWDATA>
    <ROW F20="0" F14="1" F13="FUBAR"/>
    <ROW F20="1" F14="0" F13="FIDO"/>
</ROWDATA>
```

JSON

```
"rowdata": [
    {
        "F20": "0",
        "F14": "1",
        "F13": "FUBAR"
    },
    {
        "F20": "1",
        "F14": "0",
        "F13": "FIDO"
    }
],
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is going to help, but I found this works for me.
Inside my serializer I override the handleType() method like so:

```
public class MapToTuple extends JsonSerializer<Map<String, Property>> {

     @Override
     public void serialize(final Map<String, Property> map, final JsonGenerator jgen, final SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
          /*Serializing code here*/
     }

     @Override
     public Class<Map<String, Property>> handledType() {
         Class<Map<String, Property>> typeClass = (Class<Map<String, Property>>)(Class<?>)Map.class;
         return typeClass;
     }
}
```

And then I register the serializer like this:

```
    SimpleModule mapSerializerModule = new SimpleModule("MapSerializerModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, "beta"));
    mapSerializerModule.addSerializer(new MapToTuple());

    mapper.registerModule(mapSerializerModule);
```

Hope this helps.